# Gradle build failing to read the classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build

My gardle build is failing when I am trying to run gradle clean build. The classes are in `oa-common-3.0.0.jar` and I have included it in the `lib` directory but still its failing to read the jar on runtime..Any suggestion what I am doing wrong

My build.gradle

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
       dirs 'lib'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        credentials {
            username "${artifactory_user}"
            password "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
    implementation files('lib/oa-common-3.0.0.jar')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors')
```

And the Error ::

```
$ gradle clean build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :compileJava
Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.4.7.Final
C:\Users\502622018\moa-workspace\ooa-dashboard-svc\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\common\config\cloud\CloudPlatformSecuirtyResourceServerConfig.java:40: error: package com.ge.predix.uaa.token.lib does not exist
import com.ge.predix.uaa.token.lib.FastTokenServices;
                                  ^
C:\Users\502622018\moa-workspace\ooa-dashboard-svc\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\common\config\cloud\CloudPlatformSecuirtyResourceServerConfig.java:41: error: package com.ge.predix.uaa.token.lib does not exist
import com.ge.predix.uaa.token.lib.FastTokenServicesCreator;
                                  ^
C:\Users\502622018\moa-workspace\ooa-dashboard-svc\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\common\config\cloud\CloudPlatformSecuirtyResourceServerConfig.java:176: error: cannot find symbol
        public FastTokenServices setFastTokenBean() {
               ^
  symbol:   class FastTokenServices
  location: class CloudPlatformSecuirtyResourceServerConfig
C:\Users\502622018\moa-workspace\ooa-dashboard-svc\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\overhaul\config\SwaggerConfig.java:3: error: package springfox.documentation.builders does not exist
import static springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage;
                                              ^
C:\Users\502622018\moa-workspace\ooa-dashboard-svc\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\overhaul\config\SwaggerConfig.java:3: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage;
^
C:\Users\502622018\moa-workspace\ooa-dashboard-svc\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\overhaul\config\SwaggerConfig.java:4: error: package springfox.documentation.spi does not exist
import static springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2;
                                         ^
C:\Users\502622018\moa-workspace\ooa-dashboard-svc\src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\overhaul\config\SwaggerConfig.java:4: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2;
```